# Freeware includes ssh terminal and file transfer support for Mac OS?

Tags: macos, terminal, software-recommendation, ssh, file-transfer

1. I am looking for a freeware (like Bitvise SSH Client on Windows) that keeps track of servers/connections via a GUI and support some features:

   - SSH terminal.
   - File transfer (FTP, SFTP, SCP ...).
   - Port forwarding .
2. In the absence of any freeware that meets the features in section 1. I will choose the most suitable software (cost, features, utilities ...).
   I have tried the free version of the softwares below:

   - Royal TSX
   - Terminus
   - sFTP client

Would you like to share your experience with me ?

Thanks for anything helpful.

Comment: You can use SSH etc. from any shell within Terminal already, you can also trigger SSH and SFTP connections directly from Terminal (shift-cmd-K). If this doesn't work for you, please describe in more detail what you actually need and what kind of research you've already done.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
I can use the Terminal, but it is quite inconvenient and time consuming to enter host information to connect.
For example, when I need to access a host to execute both commands in the terminal and transfer the file, I have to enter the host's information twice to connect.
So I was looking for a freeware that has a user interface that allows stores of hosts information first. Then when I need to access the host, I just need to select the host and choose the function I want to use (terminal or file transfer).

Answer (score 2):

## UNIX Philosophy

macOS is built upon a UNIX philosophy. In your situation, that means many smaller dedicated tools instead of [one monolithic tool](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client). Most of the features you want are part of built-in macOS tools. These tools are accessible by macOS's included **Terminal.app**.

- For Secure Shell connections, use `ssh`
- For network file transfers, use `scp` or `rsync`
- Port forwarding is typically part of your router's interface, not the local computer.

Comment: Exactly I need a monolithic tool that integrates the features as I have listed.

Comment: @ThangDang consider building your own workflows and tool chains using AppleScript, Automator, or shell scripts. If you have questions about how to achieve particular steps, please [ask new questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).